# Why does the Ubuntu Software application think I am offline when I am online for all other applications and services?

Tags: updates, update-manager, connection

I can update my system using apt and the Software Updater application on my Ubuntu 21.04 laptop. But I can not longer use the Ubuntu Software application. It keeps telling me "Go online to check for updates" and the update button top left is grayed out. I can install applications with Ubuntu Software. It's only checking for updates that doesn't work. I have checked repositories, even switched to another mirror, but Ubuntu Software still claims I am not online. No other applications have problems with internet connection either.

What can I do to convince Ubuntu Software that I am online so I can use it for update checks? It also checks for firmware updates so I would like to have it working. See screenshot for the error I am getting The Network Settings button does nothing:

[image: Ubuntu Software update]

There's some other oddities going on with Ubuntu Software application also. If I knew how to reset this application (which is a snap I guess?) to default I'm sure I would solve the problem above also.

Comment: Same problem for me. Thanks for your post. The snap version of Ubuntu Software has become a little annoying (it won't handle .debs "open with" from Firefox since snap containment doesn't let it access the temporary folder Firefox puts the file in)
The gnome app works, but it won't let you update without rebooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Snap and Ubuntu Software. I reported it [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/the-ubuntu-software-application-refuses-to-see-that-i-am-online/24981). I am sure it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

it is now fixed if you do

```
sudo snap refresh
```